# iOS map custom calloutView does not work with voiceOver

Tags: ios, mkmapview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When the VoiceOver is On, I can't select my custom callout view on iOS map. I just can select the map annotation to see the callout and when I want to select the callout, the street comes on top of my callout view.

I am using SMCalloutView as a custom calloutView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi shima, did you find any solutions? If yes can you please share it.

Comment: The standard Map CalloutView has not this kind of problems. I have changed the custom calloutView to standard one!